# Vee-validate and Vue-I18n localization not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate, vue-i18n

I am using Using

- "vee-validate": "3.0.0",
- "vue": "2.6.10",
- "vue-i18n": "8.14.0"

I am trying to change the language from vee-validate messages for a custom rule. The validation localization doesn't change. What am I doing wrong ?

here is my code sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-30-vuei18n-integration-forked-o3frf?file=/src/components/Example.vue

As we can see, I can change the i18n.locale but it doesn't update the messages from vee-validate V3.0.0

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a callback to custom message, not the translated value, so it will be called when to locale changes and generate new message.

vee-validate.js

```
extend("atLeastOneDigit", {
  validate(value) {
    var digitPattern = /\d+/g;
    return value.match(digitPattern) != null;
  },
  message: () => i18n.t("pwDigitError")
});
```